# Is there a symbol to represent the composition of a series of functions?

Tags: notation, function-and-relation-composition

The sigma notation for a sum is a symbol representing the addition of a series of numbers (and functions and a lot of other things) with an upper and lower bound.

It is similar with the uppercase pi notation representing multiplication.

I have not been able to find one for the composition of a series of functions. For example, I could notate $f_1\circ f_2\circ ...\circ f_n(x)$ as something like this:

$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\foo}{\text{$\Large \bigcirc$}}\left(\foo\limits^n_{i=1}f_i\right)(x)$$

I know that this is probably not a correct or standard way to notate it. That is why I am asking how it should be notated.

Comment: I don’t think there is a standard notation. Your proposal seems reasonable but you’d need to explain it (in particular, to fix the order $f_1\circ\cdots\circ f_n$ vs $f_n\circ\cdots\circ f_1$).